# How to reuse SelectList editor on display pages in Cofoundry

Tags: c#, cofoundry

For various reasons I want to show an editable version of a data model in Cofoundry. My data model has an enumeration field and in the administration interface, I can make it show up as a select list by adding the SelectList attribute:

```
[Display(Name = "Tenant type")]
[SelectList(typeof(TenantTypeType))]
public TenantTypeType TenantType { get; set; }
```

Now I'm implementing the display page for the data model, where I cheat a bit and simply include the data model in the display model:

```
public class BookingDisplayModel : ICustomEntityPageDisplayModel<BookingDataModel>
{
  public string PageTitle { get; set; }
  public string MetaDescription { get; set; }

  public BookingDataModel Booking { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want an editor for the `TenantType` in my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomEntity.Model.Booking.TenantType, new { @class = "form-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CustomEntity.Model.Booking.TenantType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately ASP.NET Core does not have a built-in select list for enums ... but Cofoundry obviously have.

Question: what razor code should I add to generate editor elements in the same way as the Cofoundry admin interface does? I practically just want to edit a single entity/data model just like in the Cofoundry admin interface - but I want to present it to non-admins in a "normal" page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cofoundry, UI elements are designed for the admin panel only. As of v0.9 they are written in AngularJS specifically for the admin panel and at some point in the future will likely be rewritten using a more modern framework.

In general, Cofoundry takes an unobtrusive approach to integrating into your application, therefore it does not dictate a specific framework, style or layout for your website/application - that is up to you to implement, so in this case you will need to build out your own select list.